# Talmid Rabbeinu Yeĥiel of Paris on Moed Katan

Tags: talmud-gemara, commentaries, talmud-bavli, tosfot, masechet-moed-katan

Steinsaltz edition of Moed Katan cites a comment on daf 17a from Talmid Rabbeinu Yeĥiel of Paris. This doesn’t appear in Tosafot. Does anyone know where I might find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for for?
https://www.hebrewbooks.org/14752